# How can I get a function to repeat itself 5 times within another function? (Rock Paper Scissors)

Tags: javascript

I'm building the script to a rock paper scissors game and I got the computer to randomly return "Rock, Paper or Scissors" here

```
function computerPlay() {
      let computerOption = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
      return computerOption[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerOption.length)];
}
```

and I got the computer to play against me (if I constantly chose 'rock') here

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
      if (computerSelection == 'Paper') {
         return 'You lose! Paper beats Rock!';
      } else if (computerSelection == 'Rock') {
         return 'You tied! Nobody wins.';
      } else {  
          return 'You win! Rock beats Scissors!';
      } 
}
const playerSelection = 'Rock'
const computerSelection = computerPlay()
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))
```

The part I am having trouble with is creating a function to have the computer play against me 5 times in a row in a new function game(). I haven't learned looping yet, i'm learning through TOP and they are suggesting to just use my playRound() function 5 times in a row and console.log the result after every game.

```
function game() {
      playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
      console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
      playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
      console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
      playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
      console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
      playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
      console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
      playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
      console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
}
```

When I call the function game()  I keep getting console.log to return me the same value 5 times so I feel it's only running the game once and just displaying the results 5 times. Any help would be appreciated into how I may be able to get the game to actually run 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the `computerSelection` *inside* the `playRound` function, so that a new random computer choice is generated on each game:

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let computerOption = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
  return computerOption[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerOption.length)];
}

function playRound() {
  const playerSelection = 'Rock'
  const computerSelection = computerPlay()
  if (computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return 'You lose! Paper beats Rock!';
  } else if (computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return 'You tied! Nobody wins.';
  } else {
    return 'You win! Rock beats Scissors!';
  }
}

function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(playRound());
  }
}

game();
```

Or, for a cheap interactive version with `prompt`:

```js
const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
function computerPlay() {
  return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
}

function playRound() {
  let playerSelection;
  while (!choices.includes(playerSelection)) {
    playerSelection = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissors?');
    if (playerSelection === null) {
      throw new Error('exiting');
    }
  }
  const computerSelection = computerPlay()
  if (computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return 'You lose! Paper beats Rock!';
  } else if (computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return 'You tied! Nobody wins.';
  } else {
    return 'You win! Rock beats Scissors!';
  }
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
async function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(playRound());
    await delay(50); // give Stack Snippet console time to render
  }
}

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to your `game()`.  Alternatively you can use `game2` to call them in loop.

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let computerOption = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  return computerOption[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerOption.length)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (computerSelection == "Paper") {
    return "You lose! Paper beats Rock!";
  } else if (computerSelection == "Rock") {
    return "You tied! Nobody wins.";
  } else {
    return "You win! Rock beats Scissors!";
  }
}
const playerSelection = "Rock";

function game() {
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
  console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()));
}

const game2 = () =>
  Array.from(new Array(5), () =>
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerPlay()))
  );

game();
game2();
```